# Creating generic shell script for spark-submit

Tags: shell, apache-spark

We have a Configuration driven ETL framework built on top of Apache Spark and we are in the process of designing a common shell script that can be used for doing the spark-submit.

We looked at various blog posts and spark documentation to get some direction for our work but all we see is the specification for spark-submit ( Just like UNIX man page ) but what we are looking for is some kind of how-to article or best practices that can be followed while designing common shell script for spark-submit.

Here is our plan so far.

To set the context for our shell script, assume that we have many applications in our project and each of the applications will have many jobs.

Environment Details:
Spark Version: 2.3.2,
Deployment Mode: Cluster,
Programming Language: Scala,
Scala Version: 2.11.8,
Cluster Manage: YARN

The core of our script is using the `--properties-file` option that comes with spark-submit command. All the configuration that we set through `"--conf"` should come from the configuration file and we can make use of `--properties-file` option to pass the configuration file as an input. This way we are making the shell script immune to the configuration changes.

To enable the selection of configurations dynamically, we are planning to have many configuration files as listed below

1. Based on memory - we will have many files for each of the memory-related categories (x-small, small, medium, large, x-large). All the memory-related properties like cores and memory for driver and executor based on category go here.
2. Common - All the common properties like (jars, convertMetastoreParquet, and any other common conf go here.
3. Application-Specification specific properties or overrides can go here.

We will get the application name, memory sizing category as an input to the shell script, and based on the memory category, we choose the corresponding conf file. Contents of which are appended with the common conf file and then if there are application-specific override (optional) then Application-specific file also appended with the existing configuration.  Finally, the consolidated file is passed as an input to the `--properties-file` option.

What I wanted to know is

1. Are there any blogs/videos that list down the best practices for designing the shell script.
2. We are planning to use dynamic memory allocation so we are not setting the instance parameter through the configuration files. Is there any downside to using dynamic memory allocation in production cluster other than the additional time taken for provisioning/decommissioning the resources during run time.

Thanks

Comment: _"Is there any downside to using dynamic memory allocation in production cluster"_ > you did not even mention which kind of cluster - Kubernetes? Spark Standalone? Mesos? YARN?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Ours is YARN. I will update the question.